# Need advice with tkinter GUI - inconsistent button positioning

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, grid

Please have a look at the following snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


# Grid variables
width = 6
mid_left = int(width/2 - 1)
mid_right = int(width/2)
pady_5 = 5


# Main window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Controller')


# Top frame
top_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
top_frame.grid(row=0, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Arm Movement')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move to Center Position')
button_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, sticky='e', pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move to Last Position')
button_2.grid(row=1, column=mid_right, sticky='w', pady=pady_5)

entry_3_1 = tk.Entry(top_frame)
entry_3_1.grid(row=2, column=mid_left, pady=pady_5)
label_3_1 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='X:')
label_3_1.grid(row=2, column=mid_left-1, sticky='e', pady=pady_5)

entry_3_2 = tk.Entry(top_frame)
entry_3_2.grid(row=2, column=mid_right+1, pady=pady_5)
label_3_2 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Y:')
label_3_2.grid(row=2, column=mid_right, sticky='e', pady=pady_5)

button_3 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move!')
button_3.grid(row=2, column=mid_right+2, sticky='w', pady=pady_5)


# Center frame
center_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
center_frame.grid(row=1, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(center_frame, text='Execution')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(center_frame, text='Quick Routine')
button_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, sticky='e', pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(center_frame, text='Full Routine')
button_2.grid(row=1, column=mid_right, sticky='w', pady=pady_5)


# Bottom frame
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
bottom_frame.grid(row=2, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text='Reconstruction')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Quick')
button_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, sticky='e', pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Full')
button_2.grid(row=1, column=mid_right, sticky='w', pady=pady_5)


# Open main window
main_window.mainloop()
```

If you run this example, you'll see that the two uppermost buttons "Move to Center Position" and "Move to Last Position" aren't centered like the rest of the buttons. Furthermore, the entry fields are seemingly arbitrarily placed far apart even though they're supposed to be right next to each other and centered. What is causing these inconsistencies and how can I resolve them?

Or is there a better way *to begin with* to place GUI elements than using the `grid` method? I'm running into 'stupid' problems such as 'having to decide' between even and odd number of grid columns: Choose an even number of columns (such as in above example) and you cannot center elements (as there is no center column) vs. choose an odd number of columns and you cannot center two elements side-by-side. Using the `pack` method quickly fell out of favor as it's way too limited.

**UPDATE**: Just want to illustrate that no matter how one tweaks the code, there seems to be an invisible, additional layer of code inside the `grid` method that keeps shifting elements around arbitrarily. It appears to be impossible to get clean, reliable positioning. Take a look at the button positions here, specifically the complete lack of effect of using either `sticky='e'` or `='w'` on the positioning of buttons `Move to Center Position` and `Move to Last Position`:

```
import tkinter as tk


# Grid variables
width = 6
mid_left = int(width/2 - 1)
mid_right = int(width/2)
padx_5 = 10
pady_5 = 5


# Main window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Controller')


# Top frame
top_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
top_frame.grid(row=0, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Arm Movement')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move to Center Position')
button_1.grid(row=3, column=mid_right, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move to Last Position')
button_2.grid(row=3, column=mid_left, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)

label_3_1 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='X [cm]:')
label_3_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left-1, sticky='e', padx=(20, 0), pady=pady_5)
entry_3_1 = tk.Entry(top_frame)
entry_3_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, pady=pady_5)

label_3_2 = tk.Label(top_frame, text='Y [cm]:')
label_3_2.grid(row=2, column=mid_left-1, sticky='e', padx=(20, 0), pady=pady_5)
entry_3_2 = tk.Entry(top_frame)
entry_3_2.grid(row=2, column=mid_left, pady=pady_5)

button_3 = tk.Button(top_frame, text='Move!')
button_3.grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=mid_left+1, sticky='w', padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)


# Center frame
center_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
center_frame.grid(row=1, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(center_frame, text='Execution')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(center_frame, text='Quick Routine')
button_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(center_frame, text='Full Routine')
button_2.grid(row=1, column=mid_right, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)


# Bottom frame
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
bottom_frame.grid(row=2, pady=pady_5)

label_0 = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text='Reconstruction')
label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=width, pady=pady_5)

button_1 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Quick')
button_1.grid(row=1, column=mid_left, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Full')
button_2.grid(row=1, column=mid_right, padx=padx_5, pady=pady_5)


# Open main window
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use ```.place``` which allows you to place your widget anywhere you wish within the master

Comment: Look into `columnspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: Thx, I'll look into `place`... I'm also playing around with `columnspan`and `rowspan`, but found them not helpful in this context as they seem to just shift around my buttons in an unpredictable manner. It would be helpful if one could find out the mechanics under the hood of `tkinter`, i.e. how positions, sizes etc. are computed mathematically and based on what input parameters/variables. Or simply put, if things would be a little more consistent with less voodoo required

Comment: I would suggest that You use frames, actually I am a bit confused too, but... I usually use frames (which allow to shift between layout managers btw)

Comment: Ok, will try it with grouping of elements by frames... What are layout managers, btw?

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"It would be helpful if one could find out the mechanics under the hood of tkinter,"_ - good news, you can! See [Grid algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/grid.htm#M33) in the canonical tk man pages.

Comment: The documentation is a mess as it's lacking examples and there seems to exist at least two or three different versions of `tkinter` with different syntaxes. Try looking up the issue of centering elements within a frame - you'll see varying suggestions for options like `anchor`, `sticky` etc. most of which don't work. Examples for `sticky`: `TclError: bad stickyness value "center": must be a string containing n, e, s, and/or w` for `sticky=center`, syntax errors for `sticky='w+e'` vs. `sticky='we'` vs. `sticky=w+e` etc. - a productivity killer! -.-

Comment: Moreover, this documentation does not appear to contain Python syntax...it looks more like command line syntax. If I'd be trying to obfuscate my package syntax as much as possible, this is probably what I'd come up with

Comment: By the way, for some reason `rowspan` doesn't seem to work on the `Move!` button. I tried to make the button span over both the `X:` and `Y:` entry rows, but it doesn't work

Comment: _"Moreover, this documentation does not appear to contain Python syntax"_ - yes, the documentation I linked to is for tcl/tk. Tcl/tk is the foundation for tkinter, and its documentation is the ultimate source of truth for how tk behaves. I apologize for not being more clear, I have a bad habit of assuming people have read the first two paragraphs of the official tkinter documentation where it mentions this fact: _"The tkinter package is a thin object-oriented layer on top of Tcl/Tk. To use tkinter, you don’t need to write Tcl code, but you will need to consult the Tk documentation,"_

Comment: It's a bit hard to give a really good answer since we don't know what layout you're trying to achieve since you've shown two blocks of code with two different layouts.  It might help if you could use ascii art or a hand drawing to show the layout you desire. We could then give better recommendations on how to achieve it.  It looks like you're creating a UI that doesn't naturally fit in a grid - you want everything centered, but some rows have an even number of objects and some have an odd number.  You can do that, but it may require an extra frame or two to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay, then why are there four different versions of `columnconfigure`, `grid_columnconfigure`, `grid.columnconfigure`, and `grid columnconfigure` in `tkinter`? Even if you eliminate a pair as a syntax issue as you explained, multiple documentations and also SO posts refer to both `columnconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` and it's not clear when to use which

Comment: E.g. I already encountered the issue that applying `weight` to adjust adjacent frame sizes worked with one, but not the other. I can post another, more detailed example if you wish... Are these methods the same, or different, or "kind of" same, but yet different...

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"Okay, then why are there four different versions of columnconfigure, grid_columnconfigure, grid.columnconfigure, and grid columnconfigure in tkinter"_ - I don't know why the developers chose to have multiple names for the same function. They are literally the same function, however. `columnconfigure`  is literally defined in the source code as `columnconfigure = grid_columnconfigure`.

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"I already encountered the issue that applying weight to adjust adjacent frame sizes worked with one, but not the other. "_ - that cannot be true. The two functions are literally the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put the two buttons in the same frame (`top_frame`) of the widgets at row 2, so their positions will be affected by those widgets.

You can use another frame to hold the two buttons and put that frame at row 1 of `top_frame`:

```py
# frame for the two buttons
top_inner_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame)
top_inner_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=width)

button_1 = tk.Button(top_inner_frame, text='Move to Center Position')
button_1.pack(size="left", pady=pady_5)

button_2 = tk.Button(top_inner_frame, text='Move to Last Position')
button_2.pack(size="left", pady=pady_5)
```

Comment: Hi, why does putting those buttons in the same `top_frame` cause any issue? Aren't `grid` coordinates the same within the same child? Or should I create new inner frames for every set of buttons/elements?

Comment: If number of widgets in two rows are different, it may be difficult to layout them as you want.  Putting them in different frames is more easier to arrange them basically.

Comment: Yes, this I see from the simple problem of e.g. centering two vs. three elements. But how is this seemingly nondeterministic/arbitrary behavior introduced? It reminds me a little bit of LaTeX, where you sometimes have to use a "crowbar" and force things into place. If I define a mathematical grid and place elements on it, I'd expect those elements to "obey" and not some abstraction layer introducing arbitrarity changes. For example, if I arrange `matplotlib` subplots on a grid, they actually end up on a grid and not get shifted around left and right

Comment: See also added example in the question. A bit cleaner GUI - but `tkinter` is still behaving unpredictably. It feels like using a screwdriver with an additional joint that makes the end flop around uncontrollably

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"But how is this seemingly nondeterministic/arbitrary behavior introduced?"_ - the behavior isn't non-deterministic. The grid algorithm is accurately described in the canonical documentation: [The grid algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/grid.htm#M33)

Comment: ...which, unfortunately, is neither very canonical nor usable. :/  It looks like the documentation is written either for a different package or for a 30 years older version, in some other language than Python, and with functions intended to be called from the command line/terminal (the lingo is more reminiscent to a Linux `man` page with options/flags etc.). The documentation also lacks useful examples (in **Python**). The author should spend some time to https://readthedocs.org/ and learn how Python docs are written

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"...which, unfortunately, is neither very canonical nor usable."_ - it is both. What you don't seem to have gotten from the python tkinter documentation is that tkinter is a wrapper around tcl/tk. The reason the documentation is canonical is that it comes from the tcl/tk project. As you guessed, it is indeed written in some other language. You must do a very basic translation to use that documentation for python. The python docs cover this in the [Tkinter Life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand this is because you are using the .grid() function.

Grid is great because it's simple, but it's not meant to be precise placing. There are two other functions for placing widgets, .pack() and .place(). I suspect you knew of .pack() and .grid() and thought the grid was for more specific placing, as pack allows almost no control of placing/spacing. .place() is almost definitely the method you're looking for though.

.place() instead of grid takes three arguments, x value, y value and anchor location. You can even use relative x and y values so it will always appear in the same spot in the window regardless of window size! I really love the method.

for example

```
your_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) #places widget dead center of the window, with an anchor in the middle of the widget
```

You can anchor from a lot of different places on the widget as well, for example, anchor=NW instead of anchor=CENTER in the above code would align the top left corner of the widget to the center of the window.

Comment: Okay, I've given up on `place` as I'd like to avoid having to define position values by myself. Also, `anchor=CENTER` does not seem to compute. It's either `anchor='center'` or the CENTER option has been removed altogether leaving only `'n/e/w/s'` and some combinations - although it's not clear whether or not single quotes are required (i.e. input as a string or a variable). Ooff...

Comment: No quotes. Just CENTER in all caps. You can also use the N, E, W, S as well as combinations for corners such as NW, NE, etc. I'm not sure why it's not working for you, I have used it many, many times including in a GUI program which is currently nearly 2 KLOCs.

Comment: @Matt: the way they imported tkinter, they can't use `CENTER`. It would have to be `tk.CENTER`, or just the literal string `"center"` would work just as well.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I hadn't considered that they imported as tk; generally I just see the "from tkinter import *" Either way, .place() should be an effective alternative that would accomplish the goals of the post, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, each column will be just wide enough to fit its contents. You haven't done anything to change that. Therefore, columns 2 and 3 are not going to be at the center of the 6-column frame.

Here is a visualization of the grid cells in `top_frame`. Note: column zero isn't visible because it has a width of 0.

[image: screenshot of original configuration]

You can easily verify that by forcing all of the columns to be the same size. When you do that, the buttons will be perfectly centered. Of course, some of your other widgets will not be where you expect.

To set the columns to a uniform width, give them all the same value for the `uniform` attribute. It doesn't matter what the value is, as long as it's the same. This has to be done after `top_frame` has been created.

Although the tkinter documentation implies that `columnconfigure` accepts a single index, the tcl/tk documentation makes it clear that you can give a list of indexes. Since `width` represents the total number of columns in your code we can use the following to configure columns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 to have a `uniform` value of `1`:

```
top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(tuple(range(width)), uniform=1)
```

Note: tkinter has two names for this function: `columnconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure`. One is simply an alias for the other.

Here is the visualization of the frame with uniform column widths:

[image: screenshot of uniform column widths]

I'm guessing that you don't want all of the columns to have the same width, since that forces the UI to be wider than it needs to be. If I were writing this code I would use a separate frame for the row with the entry widgets, which is what seems to be throwing your design off with both very narrow and very wide columns.

### Documentation

The canonical description of the grid algorithm, along with the available options for the various grid commands (`grid`, `grid_columnconfigure`, etc) is available in the
[tcl/tk man pages for the grid command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/grid.htm). An explanation of how to translate tcl/tk man pages into tkinter documentation can be found in the official python tkinter documentation, in a section titled [Tkinter Life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver).

Comment: Hi, thanks. This looks very interesting, although I don't understand the syntax. Do you know how to interpret the documentation on `columnconfigure` (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/grid.htm#M8)? It looks like some weird command line syntax, but I need Python syntax. For example, it doesn't say anywhere that I need to pass a Python tuple. Also, `uniform` is described as an "option" that needs a "value", but what does it mean? Does it have to evaluate to a boolean, an integer, ...?

Comment: ...for example, if I have 6 columns, do I need to plug in a tuple `(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2)` to get columns of width 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, and 2? If so, why the extra option `uniform`? In this example, the widths are not uniform - so will doing `uniform=1` throw an exception or lead to voodoo behavior?

Comment: @michaela_karl: _" Do you know how to interpret the documentation on columnconfigure "_ - there is an example of calling `columnconfigure` in my answer. The official tkinter docs give hints at how to translates tcl/tk documentation into python  in the [Tkinter Life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver)

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"for example, if I have 6 columns, do I need to plug in a tuple (2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2) to get columns of width 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, and 2?"_ - no. If the first argument is a tuple, it represents a list of column numbers. They will all be given the same options specified in the command. `tuple(range(width))` resolves to `(0,1,2,3,4,5)`, which means that columns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 will all receive the value of 1 for the `uniform` option.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version of the code is like this html table (root) with nested tables (frames).

[image]

Elements do not move randomly. They depend on each other within the same frame.
Each frame is a separate system that adjusts to the contents of its cells.
Frames are independent of each other but depend on the root window.

Two columns and one frame are enough. One system for all elements.

Try something like this:

```
      |      col 0     |     col 1     |
------|----------------------------------
row 0 |           Arm Movement         | columnspan=2
------|----------------------------------
row 1 | Move to Center |  Move to Last | sticky='ew' for both
------|----------------------------------
row 2 |       X:       |       Y:      | sticky='ew' for both
------|----------------------------------
row 3 |    Entry X     |    Entry Y    |
------|----------------------------------
row 4 |               Move!            | columnspan=2
------|----------------------------------
row 5 |            Execution           |
------|----------------------------------
row 6 | Quick Routine  |  Full Routine | 
------|----------------------------------
row 7 |           Reconstruction       |
------|----------------------------------
row 8 |          Quick | Full          | 
------|----------------------------------

Entry X: sticky='w' and padx
Entry Y: sticky='e' and padx
```

Comment: This doesn't show any code, and it appears that the result is different from what the OP wants since the entries are below their labels rather than next to them.

Comment: @BryanOakley I do not presume to say what exactly the author of the question wants. But it seems there are problems with centering the elements in the window. Perhaps the person is trying to find a design so that everything looks balanced. In the second version, the entries are already arranged differently.

Comment: Thanks, many useful answers here, but I think you got the core of the problem... It's okay not to include actual code, sometimes pseudocode/structural schematic is more useful. Will try this suggestions

Comment: And yes, despite what the question might suggest, I'm not actually into wasting weeks OCD'ing with voodoo style code...IMHO style should reflect the amount of information put in by the user. Less information => more symmetry. A bit like `LyX` when using `LaTeX` - you throw in your content with little to no extra adjustments and the style output is already 80-90% or "pretty okay". One can invest more energy to tweak for 95-99%, but the framework should reflect Pareto's principle in order to maximize productivity

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that neither `sticky='ew'` nor `sticky='nesw` expands buttons/elements to their grid cell border. There is still voodoo code in `tkinter` that sizes elements arbitrarily

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"Unfortunately, I can confirm that neither sticky='ew' nor sticky='nesw expands buttons/elements to their grid cell border. "_ - that is simply not true. The `sticky` option absolutely will make the widgets expand to fill the grid cell border. There is no "voodoo code" in tkinter - the behavior is deterministic, and is documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, there **is** voodoo and at least some of it cannot be explained away by pointing towards Tcl/Tk. Example: I tried adjusting `weight` while trying to apply @8349697's suggestion, but it failed with `columnconfigure()`, while it seems to work with `grid_columnconfigure()`. And the fun part is that several discussions seem to mix these methods up as if they are the same. But then why two different names and the differing behavior?

Comment: @michaela_karl: _"Yes, there is voodoo and at least some of it cannot be explained away by pointing towards Tcl/Tk. Example:"_ - I respectfully disagree. Tcl/tk is _decades_ old, and a glaring problem like this would have been noticed and fixed years ago. You're simply misinterpreting the results. I can't explain what you're seeing because I don't know what code you're using to get the result you claim.

Comment: @michaela_karl: `columnconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` cannot give different results. They are literally the same function.